# A default choice in my select in angular JS and delete underscore between two words

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello everybody I am using AngularJS to create an application web.

I would like to show city 02 as a default choice in my select and to delete the underscote between the two words underscore like city_02, like to show city, city 02, city 03 instead of city, city_02, city_03 of my select

```
<select ng-model="selectedCity"  ng-options="x for (x, y) in cities">
</select>
```

and this is my script js:

```
$scope.cities = {
    city : [
    {id:'c01' , name:'name1', price:15},
    {id:'c02' , name:'name2', price:18},
    {id:'c03' , name:'name3', price:11},
  ],
    city_02 : [
    {id:'cc01' , name:'name11', price:10},
    {id:'cc02' , name:'name22', price:14},
    {id:'cc03' , name:'name33', price:11},
  ],
    city_03 : [
    {id:'ccc01' , name:'name111', price:19},
    {id:'ccc02' , name:'name222', price:18},
    {id:'ccc03' , name:'name333', price:10},
  ]
    };
```

Anybody Has an idea please. Thanks

Comment: what underscore? as for the default value you can always manually set `selectedCity`'s value to the value you want as default

Comment: underscore =_ . I need to keep selectedCity do you have another idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show city 02 as the default selected value simply set your `$scope.selectedCity = 'city_02'`.

To eliminate the underscore when displaying in your select add the following filter:

```
.filter('cityFilter', function() {
    return function(city) {
        return city.replace('_', ' ');
    }
})
```

Then use it in your `ng-options` like this:

```
ng-options="x as (x | cityFilter) for (x, y) in cities"
```

Comment: I set mine $scope.selectedCity = 'city_02' but doesn't work with me

Comment: Yes you're right but I have another issue. I used the same ng-model in other tag : <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedCity"> this occured a problem of duplicate key.
Error: ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater

when I use this <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedCity"> it couldn't chose which one will selected, do you see what I mean ?

Comment: That seems unrelated to this and would be better addressed in a separate question.

Comment: done this is my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242995/how-to-iterate-my-matrix-when-i-use-a-filter

Comment: Can you see my new question please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596612/populate-dropdown-2-based-on-dropdown-1-selection-and-how-to-iterate-when-i-chos