# how to iterate my matrix when I use a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello everyone I am working with ArgularJs. I need to fix this problem, when I use a filter, I can't iterate my matrix to show its values into my table.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="x as (x | cityFilter) for (x, y) in cities">
    </select>
</div>

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedCity">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my script js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('cityFilter', function() {
    return function(city) {
        return city.replace('_', ' ');
    }
})
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cities = {
        city: [{
            id: 'c01',
            name: 'name1',
            price: 15
        }, {
            id: 'c02',
            name: 'name2',
            price: 18
        }, {
            id: 'c03',
            name: 'name3',
            price: 11
        }],
        city_02: [{
            id: 'cc01',
            name: 'name11',
            price: 10
        }, {
            id: 'cc02',
            name: 'name22',
            price: 14
        }, {
            id: 'cc03',
            name: 'name33',
            price: 11
        }],
        city_03: [{
            id: 'ccc01',
            name: 'name111',
            price: 19
        }, {
            id: 'ccc02',
            name: 'name222',
            price: 18
        }, {
            id: 'ccc03',
            name: 'name333',
            price: 10
        }]
    };

    $scope.selectedCity = 'city_02';
});
```

when I run I get this error :

```
Error: ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in selectedCity, Duplicate key: string:a, Duplicate value: a
```

I would like to show city 02 as a default choice in my select.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to do. You are passing a string to `ng-repeat` which makes no sense. Please show expected results

Comment: @charlietfl the expected results is to iterat my matrix and show its value in a table please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/bgg5yfot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

charlietfl is right in pointing out that `$scope.selectedCity` is a string and cannot be used with `ng-repeat`, you need to give it an array.

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in cities[selectedCity]">
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bgg5yfot/1/