# Populate Dropdown 2 based on Dropdown 1 selection and how to iterate when I chose a suboption

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello everyone I am working with ArgularJs 1.5. I need to populate Dropdown 2 based on Dropdown 1 selection, to show it only if it exists (if DropDown 1 selected had dropDown 2) else don't show Dropdown 2 (deactivate it) and show the values of dropDown selected (either of dropDown 1 or of dropDown 2) into my table.

In this case I have a dropDown 1 named `city` which has  3 `subcity` (dropdown 2) I would like to show them when I select `city` and iterate values (matrix) when I chose one subcity like `subcity02`

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="x as (x | cityFilter) for (x, y) in cities">
    </select>

    <select ng-model="selectedSubCity"  ng-options="x as (x | cityFilter) for (x, y) in selectedCity.subCity">
    </select>
</div>

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedCity"><!--but here I need to iterat the selectedSubCity too when I select DropDown 2-->
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my script js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('cityFilter', function() {
    return function(city) {
        return city.replace('_', ' ');
    }
})
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
  $scope.cities = {
    city : [
    {id:'c01' , name:'name1', price:15},
    {id:'c02' , name:'name2', price:18},
    {id:'c03' , name:'name3', price:11},
    {subCity01 : [
            {id:'sub01' , name:'nameSub1', price:1},
            {id:'sub02' , name:'nameSub2', price:8},
            {id:'sub03' , name:'nameSub3', price:1},
    ],
    subCity02 : [
            {id:'ssub01' , name:'nameSsub1', price:1},
            {id:'ssub02' , name:'nameSsub2', price:8},
            {id:'ssub03' , name:'nameSsub3', price:4},
    ],
    subCity03 : [
            {id:'sssub01' , name:'nameSssub1', price:1},
            {id:'sssub02' , name:'nameSssub2', price:2},
            {id:'sssub03' , name:'nameSssub3', price:1},
    ]
},
  ],
    city_02 : [
    {id:'cc01' , name:'name11', price:10},
    {id:'cc02' , name:'name22', price:14},
    {id:'cc03' , name:'name33', price:11},
  ],
    city_03 : [
    {id:'ccc01' , name:'name111', price:19},
    {id:'ccc02' , name:'name222', price:18},
    {id:'ccc03' , name:'name333', price:10},
  ]
    };
```

this don't fix my issue I can't see the dropDown 2 and I can't iterate its values. Anybody could help me please.

Comment: you dont have a property or variable selectedCity.subCity in your json.. Not sure If I am missing something... A fiddle will be really helpful

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but your JSON is super confusing. You have a city, which is an array of objects, the first 3 of which are the same, but then the next three are objects each with arrays of objects. I don't know if restructuring your JSON is an option, but it might be worth it to try to normalize a little and make it easier on your front-end code.

Comment: @Lex maybe you're right can you help me and think with me of a solution please

Comment: Not really because I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to write. Structuring your data in a usable format is really something you or someone else at your company needs to do anyway.

Comment: I would like to declare a subcity into city and recuperate it. Maybe something like $scope.subcities into $scope.cities

Comment: @Abderrahim check this demo, if I understood it right and this is your expected behavior, I will post as an answer http://plnkr.co/edit/Cy2bNp3vuWiLoLlFcy81?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first issue here is the data structure - it will not allow you simulate the expected behavior the way it is, so I changed it a little bit:

```
$scope.cities = [
         {
              name: "city A",
              elements: [{
                    id: 'c01',
                    name: 'name1',
                    price: 15
              }, {
                    id: 'c02',
                    name: 'name2',
                    price: 18
              }, {
                    id: 'c03',
                    name: 'name3',
                    price: 11
              }],
              subsities: [ {
                          name: "sub A1",
                          elements: [{
                                id: 'sub01',
                                name: 'nameSub1',
                                price: 1
                          }, {
                                id: 'sub02',
                                name: 'nameSub2',
                                price: 8
                          }, {
                                id: 'sub03',
                                name: 'nameSub3',
                                price: 1
                          } ]
                    },
                     {
                          name: "sub A2",
                          elements: [{
                                id: 'ssub01',
                                name: 'nameSsub1',
                                price: 1
                          }, {
                                id: 'ssub02',
                                name: 'nameSsub2',
                                price: 8
                          }, {
                                id: 'ssub03',
                                name: 'nameSsub3',
                                price: 4
                          } ]
                    },
                     {
                          name: "sub A3",
                          elements: [{
                                id: 'sssub01',
                                name: 'nameSssub1',
                                price: 1
                          }, {
                                id: 'sssub02',
                                name: 'nameSssub2',
                                price: 2
                          }, {
                                id: 'sssub03',
                                name: 'nameSssub3',
                                price: 1
                          }]
                    }
              ]
        },
         {
              name: "city B",
              elements: [{
                    id: 'cc01',
                    name: 'name11',
                    price: 10
              }, {
                    id: 'cc02',
                    name: 'name22',
                    price: 14
              }, {
                    id: 'cc03',
                    name: 'name33',
                    price: 11
              } ]
        },
        {
              name: "city C",
              elements: [{
                    id: 'ccc01',
                    name: 'name111',
                    price: 19
              }, {
                    id: 'ccc02',
                    name: 'name222',
                    price: 18
              }, {
                    id: 'ccc03',
                    name: 'name333',
                    price: 10
              } ]
        }
  ];
```

Second change: I added ng-change event on both dropdowns and the HTML is now :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedCity"      ng-change="extractSubsities(selectedCity)" ng-options="item as item.name for item in cities track by item.name">
  </select>

  <select ng-show="selectedCity.subsities" ng-model="selectedSubCity"      ng-change="extractSubsities(selectedSubCity)" ng-options="item2 as item2.name for item2 in selectedCity.subsities track by item2.name">
   </select>

  <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item3 in data track by item3.id">
              <!--but here I need to iterat the selectedSubCity too when I select DropDown 2-->
              <td>{{ item3.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ item3.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ item3.price }}</td>
        </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

And third - the change event:

```
$scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
    if(itemSelected && itemSelected.elements){
        $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
    }
  }
```

A full working demo is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cy2bNp3vuWiLoLlFcy81?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer I need something else I need to back and print the values of dropdown 1 after select dropdown 2 , can we do this please

Comment: @Abderrahim What do you mean by 'need to back and print'?

Comment: I mean when I select an element of subsities for example sub A1 it will print its values that right but if I would like to return to his parent (city A) and print its values. otherwise when I select sub A1 I couldn't return to city A and print its values if I want to do this I have to refresh the page

Comment: Well it prints the values of city A when after selecting the subsity, you change for example to city B and then back to cityA. So how else do you want to print city values? next to subsity values? actually, city values are still available. Check this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/yWJHgUyQ3cNvsCqzodBd?p=preview

Comment: Yes Great  just I need when I select sub A1 to print only the values of sub A1 and not the both (the values of cityA and sub A1) I need only the values of sub A1

Comment: you contradict yourself - subsities if selected, the parent has to remain selected - so how do you want to select city if it is already selected? Or you want to show subcity only if the parent city has no values? I don't get you

Comment: No in your last answer when I select city A it show me its values but when I select sub A1 it show me the values of city A and sub A1. I need to show the values of city A when I selecte it and show the values of sub A1 when I select it, you get it Sir?

Comment: But this is what happens in first demo - if you select city A, and no subcity it displays the city values, if you then select subcity, it displays the subcity values. If you want, you can just add an empty value to sibcity dropdow and set the data to selectedCity.elements when that empty is selected. Otherwise I don't understand the behavior you expect.

Comment: Let me explain more to you imagine that we have only one city (city A) in dropdown 1. we I select city A it show me its values and dropdown 2. when I select sub A1 it show me its values but If I would like to return to city A in this case I must refresh the page and select city A for return to values of city A

Comment: Add an empty option in subcity dropdown and reset data to city.elements, as per my suggestion in previous comment.

Comment: Hi again To show city 02 as the default selected value what can I do please ?

Comment: I added $scope.selectedCity = 'city 02' on my script but it doesn't work with me;

Comment: you have to ammend the extractSubsities function: http://plnkr.co/edit/3INibVxmL1XWhXWXUpCe?p=preview

Comment: @Abderrahimthis these are already details that you should do yourself. Sorry but I am not going to implement any change you need. Have a question, post it.